# MySQL localhost connect works but 127.0.0.1 does not

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know what the error could be when I can connect to my MySQL server via localhost but not via 127.0.0.1? AFAIK, these should be routed identically and no additional TCP layer should be created when using the IP.

```
$ mysql -u root -h localhost -D test # works
$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -D test # does not work
(127.0.0.1 does map to localhost/vice versa)
```

The table permissions are explicitly set to include both methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MySQL client library overrides localhost to use a Unix socket instead of a TCP/IP connection to 127.0.0.1. If you can connect to localhost but not 127.0.0.1, that suggests that it's either firewalled or not listening on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Still true for MySQL 8.0 on linux: _On Unix and Unix-like systems, a connection to localhost results in a socket-file connection._ ([doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/transport-protocols.html))

Answer (score 2):

The manual at [Connecting to the MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html) suggests using the following syntax :

```
shell> mysql --host=127.0.0.1
```

The explanation is :

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host
>   name localhost specially, in a way
>   that is likely different from what you
>   expect compared to other network-based
>   programs. For connections to
>   localhost, MySQL programs attempt to
>   connect to the local server by using a
>   Unix socket file. This occurs even if
>   a --port or -P option is given to
>   specify a port number. To ensure that
>   the client makes a TCP/IP connection
>   to the local server, use --host or -h
>   to specify a host name value of
>   127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also
>   specify the connection protocol
>   explicitly, even for localhost, by
>   using the --protocol=TCP option. For
>   example:

Answer (score 1):

MySQL client infers the protocol from the provided host.

> For a given connection, if the transport protocol is not specified explicitly, it is determined implicitly. For example, connections to localhost result in a socket file connection on Unix and Unix-like systems, and a TCP/IP connection to 127.0.0.1 otherwise.

Source: [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/transport-protocols.html)

If you are unable to connect to the server using `127.0.0.1` as *host*, it probably means that the server is not running on a TCP port or port 3306 (which is the default when not provided). In that case you can connect to it only over the socket file.