# Joomla cannot connect to MySQL using localhost

Tags: macos, connection, mysql, hosts, localhost

I have a fresh Joomla installation in a Mac OS X and I have configured a database to connect the application to. By default, Joomla uses `localhost` to connect (variable `$host`), but it does not work.

However, if I replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` it does connect. I have installed MySQL using MacPorts.

It seems this is the opposite [problem asked in another question](https://superuser.com/q/250363/72730).

What can I do to be able to use localhost instead of plain IP?

Here is my `/etc/hosts` content:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

To the hosts file, found at this location

> /private/etc/hosts

Save the hosts file and restart your web server.  The hosts file maps IP addresses, such as 127.0.0.1, with hostnames, such as localhost.

[Here](http://www.techwebtips.com/apple-mac/modify-hosts-file-mac-os-x-leopard-14/) is a tutorial on the Mac hosts file.

Comment: As you can see in my question update, my `/etc/hosts` had that line already :)