# Mysql resolving 127.0.0.1 to hostname

Tags: dns, mysql

I'm trying to connect to mysql using the command

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1
```

It comes up with the error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'mydomain.com' (using password: NO)
```

Why is 127.0.0.1 being converted into my domain name, and how can I fix it?

However, it does work if I don't specify a host (and by extension, if 'localhost' is specified).

**Edit**: It seems it resolves to the domain name when using TCP, so it also fails when using

```
mysql -h localhost --protocol=TCP
```

**Edit2**: When I use skip-name-resolve I get a similar output except `mydomain.com` is replaced with `x.x.x.x` which is the public IP of `mydomain.com`.

Comment: Are you using a password?
 mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -pMyRootPassword

actually works as intended.

Comment: The password is irrelevant. If I added 'root'@'mydomain.com' as a user it would work, but I want to connect using 'root'@'127.0.0.1'. The problem is that any mysql TCP connection made to either 127.0.0.1 or localhost gets changed into mydomain.com

Comment: Assuming you're on a Unix/Linux machine - have you got `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com` in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I had tried that, but it didn't yield any difference

Comment: No difference as in it still said `Access denied` or it still has `mydomain.com` in the user name?  If it's the latter and you definitely have removed your hostname from `/etc/hosts` then DNS must be misconfigured for `mysql` to be able to reverse lookup `127.0.0.1` to your hostname.

Comment: No difference as in the error output was exactly the same with or without that in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/250371/219095) contains hints as to finding a solution.

Comment: @DanielB I mentioned in the first edit that the issue seemed to be for TCP connections. I can however `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` which shows that mysqld is listening and accessible. I can also explicitly add a `'root'@'mydomain.com'` user and login to mysql.

Comment: @user3603149 : Did you checked whether you have provided user root with proper privilege and password

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath logging in is not the direct issue. The issue is that any attempts to connect using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` are not seen as coming from localhost or 127.0.0.1 but something else (in this case the hostname of (or) the public IP)

Comment: @garethTheRed I added Edit2 which suggests that rDNS is not the cause. It seems more like an `iptables` issue but I've tried flushing unnecessary rules etc to no avail.

Comment: You forgot to state your operating system and MySQL version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had masquerading for all external packets (including on lo). Removing/editing the `iptable -t nat POSTROUTING` rules fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you one million times for sharing this valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is caused by a hosts file entry.

Comment: No change when I only have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mysql is listening only on your public ip and not on 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I have `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

Comment: Check what tcpdump is telling you.

Comment: Running from the command line gives interactions between:
`mydomain.com.<port> > localhost.mysql`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question but 127.0.0.1 is the standard loopback address. SO if your host have this IP : 192.168.0.1
Then 192.168.0.1 = 127.0.0.1 = localhost

Comment: In mysql, these things are not the same. User accounts (and permissions) are maintained individually for each host, so 'root'@'localhost' can have a different password to 'root'@'127.0.0.1'

Comment: OK, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check /etc/hosts and make sure that 127.0.0.1 points only to localhost and not mydomain.com.  mydomain.com should be associated with the actual IP address for the server and not with localhost.localdomain.

2) It also looks like you've set the password for root on your mysql instance (actually this is a good thing).  Recommend adding the "-p" switch to your login so that it looks like:

mysql -h localhost -p

You will then be asked to enter the password for root. Hope this helps.